# Xcode 7.0 update issue with Swift 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I just faced an issue with my project written in Swift, when I updated my Xcode to the latest version; Xcode 7.0.

Xcode told me that I should convert my code to work with Swift's new syntax (Swift 2).

The problem is I could not understand how to solve some line of codes.

As an example: I'm using SwiftyJSON in my application and Xcode gives me this error you see below:

```
public struct JSON {

    public init(data:NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, error: NSErrorPointer = nil) {
        if let object: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: opt, error: error) {
            self.init(object)
        } else {
            self.init(NSNull())
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Some functions dropped some arguments and in this case the error pointer. instead it throws (which means you can call it only with try catch handling). here is swift 2.0 version of your code

```
public struct JSON 
{

    public init(data:NSData, options opt: NSJSONReadingOptions = .AllowFragments, error: NSErrorPointer = nil) 
    {
        do {
            let object:AnyObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: opt)
            self.init(data: object as! NSData)
        } catch {
            //error handling code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thumbs up would be appreciated ;)